# Objective-C Accessing Superclass Methods when Object Might be Superclass or Subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, scope

I'm an Objective-C noob working through a tutorial and I'm hitting a strange snag I want to understand better.

I'm looping to make a portfolio of stock objects that have a 50/50 chance of being a "foreignStock" or just being "stock" - the difference being a conversion rate property. The object stock is a superclass, with foreignStock being a subclass of stock.

I want to create a pointer, flip a coin to decide which type it is, and then assign the values I need. Since both the subclass and superclass have things like currentSharePrice, why can't I set them after the coin toss?

This is my main.m for review:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        // Declare portfolio and set the conversion rate
        BNRPortfolio *mikesPortfolio = [[BNRPortfolio alloc] init];
        NSUInteger globalConRate = 1.2;

        // Array of ticker names - remove them as they are used
        NSMutableArray *tickerNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [tickerNames addObject:@"ibm"];
        [tickerNames addObject:@"ppg"];
        [tickerNames addObject:@"google"];
        [tickerNames addObject:@"vrzn"];
        [tickerNames addObject:@"apple"];
        [tickerNames addObject:@"barq"];

        // Create and add the stocks to the portfolio
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            id newStock;

            // Coin flip to determine type
            NSUInteger randomType = random() % 2;
            if (randomType == 0) {

               newStock = [[BNRStockHolding alloc] init];

            } else {

                newStock = [[BNRForeignStockHolding alloc] init];
                newStock.conversionRate = globalConRate;
            }

            // Assign remaining values
            newStock.purchaseSharePrice = 15 * (random() % i);
            newStock.currentSharePrice = newStock.purchaseSharePrice * 1.4;

            NSUInteger randomTickerValue = random() % [tickerNames count];
            newStock.symbol = tickerNames[randomTickerValue];
            [tickerNames removeObjectAtIndex:randomTickerValue];

            [mikesPortfolio addHoldings:newStock];
        }
    }
```

The line inside the else{} block newStock.conversionRate... gives an Xcode pre-compile error stating "property not found for object of type __strong id" - I guess because it can't tell if newStock will actually be what I just declared it to be? But the assign statements at the end of main.m are showing the same line error as though newStock doesn't have those properties, even though BOTH classes will have access to them.

How do I make newStock understand that it will definitely be a class that has those properties but might ALSO have that conversion rate associated with the subclass?

I tried this:

```
        BNRStockHolding newStock;  <-- starting with superclass

        // Coin flip to determine type
        NSUInteger randomType = random() % 2;
        if (randomType == 0) {

           newStock = [[BNRStockHolding alloc] init];

        } else {

            newStock = [[BNRForeignStockHolding alloc] init];
            newStock.conversionRate = globalConRate;
        }
```

Which will make the errors on the bottom lines go away but still won't compile at the subclass method in the else{} block.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Anytime you say "throws an error" you need to indicate the error that you receive, and whether that is at compile time or runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm going to assume this is actually `main.m`, not `main.c`.)

Your primary mistake is using `id` rather than types.

```
 id newStock;
```

This says that `newStock` is "some kind of object, I have no idea what." In ObjC, `id` can be sent any message, but it does not have any properties. So you can't use dot-notation on it. There are ways around that (don't use dot notation), but the better solution is to use a type:

```
BNRStockHolding *newStock = nil;
```

That will cause a problem here:

```
newStock = [[BNRForeignStockHolding alloc] init];
newStock.conversionRate = globalConRate;
```

Which you can fix this way:

```
BNRForeignStockHolding *foreignStock = [[BNRForeignStockHolding alloc] init];
foreignStock.conversionRate = globalConRate;
newStock = foreignStock;
```

But if the only thing that makes a foreign stock "foreign" is that it has a conversion rate, I would strongly recommend against subclassing here. Just make all stocks have a conversion rate. If it's domestic, make the conversion rate 1.

Comment: When I declare: `BNRStockHolding *newStock;` I avoid the errors for the bottom lines but the line inside the else{} block that would only trigger if newStock turns out to be the subclass type still fails because BNRStockHolding doesn't have the conversionRate property.

Comment: Note my "which you can fix this way." You create the object as a foreign stock, configure it, and then assign it to `newStock`. That said, this is probably not a good use of subclassing.

Comment: I apologize - I commented very quickly and missed that there was more to your post. I freely admit this is an absurd use of subclassing - their use in the book is far simpler and I'm making it complicated to stretch the inheritance case. If I fix it the way you note, would I be right in saying that I will now have two pointers to the same object?

Comment: Yes, you would briefly have two pointers. Then the second pointer (`foreignStock`) would go out of scope at the `}` and go away. In most cases, inheritance is a last-choice in ObjC. It typically composes with helper objects (usually delegates) rather than subclassing. Good luck.